# IntelliJ no longer recognises JavaFX components

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, javafx, tornadofx

I managed to break my old MacBook and moved over to a new one. Upon re-installing IntelliJ and retrieving a Kotlin TornafoFX project from Git, the IDE no longer recognises any JavaFX components. I added JavaFX to the POM, which now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tornadofx-maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.60</kotlin.version>
        <tornadofx.version>1.7.17</tornadofx.version>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.tornado</groupId>
            <artifactId>tornadofx</artifactId>
            <version>${tornadofx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also get an error like this reported by the IDE:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/paint/Color
```

This did not happen on my old machine and JavaFX was not even required in the POM. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Often for me, intellij's cache gets messed up. Does a 'mvn clean package' from the terminal run successfully? Two things to try to fix intelliJ cache:
- Right click on your project, go to Maven->Reload Project
If that doesn't work, try:
- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
Once intelliJ restarts, the indexes will be rebuilt and that will get the dependencies in the right spot.

Comment: @Niro, unfortunately that doesn't solve it :( I've tried different Kotlin version and JDK versions too

Comment: What JDK do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to revert to JDK1.8. Not gonna question why...